# Simplify array of arrays in a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Before all, sorry for my english

I am trying to save multiples web responses into an array

I have something like this:

```
var array = [];

$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    success: function(e){
        array.push(e);
    }
});
```

But i get anything like this:

```
[[31312, 123213], [12321, 123123], [123213, 132132]]
```

And i want to get:

```
[321321, 321321, 32131, 321312, 321321, 321312]
```

How i can do this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: is `[31312, 123213]` a single response and are you getting three responses. Can you please explain the problem further

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
array.push(e);
```

with

```
array.push.apply(array, e);
```

If `e` is e.g. `1, 2, 3`, the first one will execute `array.push([1, 2, 3])`, while the second will execute `array.push(1, 2, 3)`, which gives you the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive function to flatten the multidimensional array into a single flat one.

```js
var data = [[31312, 123213], [12321, 123123], [123213, 132132]]

function flatten( arr ){
  return arr.reduce(function( ret, item ){
    return ret.concat( item.constructor === Array ? flatten( item ) : [ item ] );
  }, [])  
}

console.log( flatten( data ) );
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

`array = array.concat(e)`

Comment: `concat` is slightly less efficient than `push`, as it will copy the array in each iteration. It will work, though.